# Obtener un resultado con decimales en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy dividiendo dos número en excel de la siguiente manera:

352 / 440 y el resultado es: 0.80

Necesito hacer lo mismo en SQL Server, esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT,352 / 440)
```

Pero el resultado es 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El resultado es 0 porque estás haciendo la conversión después de hacer la división. Al usar una división con dos número enteros, SQL hace una "división entera", donde `352/440` es en efecto `0` (la parte entera de 0.8).

Para evitar esto hay varias formas, pero en general hay que convertir (explícitamente o implícitamente) ya sea el numerador o denominador a decimal o float.

Por ejemplo con conversión explícita:

```
SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT,352)/440;
```

O implícita:

```
SELECT 352*1.0/440;
```

Answer (score 2):

Se soluciona convirtiendo primero los Números a decimal y luego dividiendo

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(12,2),352)  /  CONVERT(decimal(12,2),440)
```